# Structure removed and

Tags: structure, navee

Updating a site I want to get rid of Structure and move to NavEE. I have set all channels to 'unmanaged' and than disabled and removed Structure.
Now I'm getting an error after editing and submitting an existing entry:

The requested module is not installed: structure

Any ideas what to do about this? 
I can go back to a earlier version and do things different. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that all of Structure is removed??
This includes the sections under `Add Ons` for Modules, Accessories, Extensions, Fieldtypes and Plugins...

Also, did you disable the Structure components via the Admin CP? or did you just delete the files???

It seems like EE thinks that some part of structure is still present...

Comment: Hi Blatant, yes, I disabled structure in the CP and deleted the files only  after I got the error. Something is still there indeed.

Comment: One thing you could do, as it seems like (_seems like_) there may be another 3rd Party mod holding onto Structure, is re-install Structure. Then once the entries are working again tackle the fields you think might be causing the issue. Then try uninstalling again. Also Make sure you temporerally set your Channels Field Groups, Statuses and Categories to none before removing Structure in case its laving sonething funny in the Status system for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's lingering. I would check your extension database table, I'm betting you still have some remnant hook rows pointing towards the Structure class!

What are the results of this query? (Note, I'm on mobile so I can't double check the table and column name, it might need adjusting)

```
SELECT * FROM exp_extensions WHERE method LIKE "%structure%";
```

The table name might actually be exp_hooks, and the column name might be class, can't remember.

**Edit**

This is definitely the query:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_extensions WHERE class LIKE "%structure%";
```

If you get any rows, Structure was almost certainly removed incorrectly (or their upd.structer.php file has bugs!).

Comment: At first I got this error running the query:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

I did find some rows where Publisher used structure stuff. Deleted those and ran your query again: empty results, zero rows.

Comment: But the original error is still there, meaning the error message is there although the entry is saved correctly.